# Using subquery in spark sql join

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a jdbc query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableC ON tableC.x_id = tableA.x_id
INNER JOIN tableD ON tableD.y_id = tableC.y_id
INNER JOIN tableE e ON (
    e.z_id = tableA.z_id
    AND e.y_id = tableC.y_id
    AND e.w_id = (
        SELECT MAX(w_id)
        FROM tableE ee
        WHERE 
            ee.z_id = tableA.z_id
            AND CONVERT_TZ(ee.ts,'UTC',tableD.tz) >= tableD.ts
    )
)
```

Now I am trying to use spark sql to perform joins with DataFrame, here is the code:

```
spark = builder.getOrCreate()
table_a_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=xx, table="tableA", properties=xx).filter(col("x_id").__eq__(1))
table_c_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=xx, table="tableC", properties=xx)
table_d_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=xx, table="tableD", properties=xx)
table_e_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=xx, table="tableE", properties=xx)

table_a_df.join(table_c_df, ["x_id"]) \
    .join(table_d_df, ["y_id"]) \
    .join(table_e_df) \
    .where(
        table_e_df.z_id == table_a_df.z_id and
        table_e_df.y_id == table_c_df.y_id) and
        --------THIRD_CONDITION <- *stucked here*
    )
```

I am using PySpark with Spark 3.3.0.
I am stucked at the last condition of the join, i.e. e.w_id = (..)

Comment: Let us know what is your issue or error.

Comment: The issue is, I am not sure how to integrate that last part of the join